# PHP: join tables query to create categories and subcategories?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `products` table that looks like this:

```
id            di_make              di_model

1             Samsung               TV656  
2             Samsung               TV555
3              Sony                 LCD33
```

I have a `makes` table that looks like this *(this is the table that i use as the category table)*:

```
id            names              

1             Samsung              
2             Samsung             
3              Sony
```

I need to create an output like this so when the category/make is clicked on, the dropdown will show the `di_model(s)` or `Subcategories` from the `products` table as subcategories:

http://jsfiddle.net/7NYhe/500/

I tried this query:

```
$sql3 ="SELECT DISTINCT products.di_make, products.di_model
FROM products
LEFT JOIN makes
ON products.di_make=makes.names";
$query3 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql3);
$existCount3 = mysqli_num_rows($query3);
if ($existCount3!=0) {

while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

$make_names = $row3["di_make"];
$make_model = $row3["di_model"];

//print "<li>".$make_names."</li>"; 

print '<li class="dropdown">'.$make_names.'
      <ul>
           '.$make_model.'
      </ul>
   </li>';


}
}
```

But this will create this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7NYhe/502/

So basically, it creates one category for each subcategory!

Could someone please advice on this issue?

**HERE IS A WORKING SQL FIDDLE OF MY CODE:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d9f68/1

Answer (score 4):

you can use this query

```
SELECT products.di_make, GROUP_CONCAT(products.di_model) as di_model 
FROM products LEFT JOIN makes ON products.di_make=makes.names 
GROUP BY products.di_make
```

you will fetch data like this by using it

```
di_make  di_model
Samsung  TV656,TV555
Sony     LCD33
```

you will get `di_model` as a string if a category have more than one product.now you can explode that string.

```
$subcategories = explode(",",$make_model)
'<li class="dropdown">'.$make_names.'
    <ul>';
      foreach($subcategories as $sub){

        '<li>'.$sub.'</li>';

      }

    '</ul>
</li>';
```

you can implement your php like it.

Comment: This is very close to what I'm trying to do but there is something wrong with the foreach because it doesn't work properly! the foreach will put the categories under another category as if it is a subcategory.

Comment: yes!! you can use foreach to create the subcategory under the category..

Comment: I have write this code just for demo. you can modified your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT products.di_make, MAX(products.di_model)
FROM products 
JOIN makes ON products.di_make=makes.names
GROUP BY products.di_make
```

Comment: This will only create ONE subcategory!